# Add value continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, numbers, addition

I have a textarea and a button and i want to add continuously the value to the textarea.
For example if i click the button twice, the textarea should display "aa", and if i click three times "aaa" and so on, basicly always add to a string if i click the button

Here is the code i have come up so far:

```
<textarea readonly="readonly" id="textarea"></textarea>
<input type ="button" value="a" id="button"/>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button').click(function() {

 $('#textarea').val(1);
 });

});
```

Comment: ... not even the ids match your HTML.

Comment: ohh i just made a short example ... sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#button').click(function() {
 var exitingVal = $('textarea').val();
 $('textarea').val(existinVal + 'a'); 

 });
 });
```

Comment: the `a` should probably be a string `'a'`.

Comment: ..and you probably want to not repeat the `$('#textarea')` - may as well just store that in a variable.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I actually wrote code on notepad so missed.

Comment: does having storing $('#textarea') will give me better performance or just for clean code ?

Comment: Better performance (obviously not in this little example, but in general you dont want to constantly scan the DOM for an element)

Comment: thanks, i asked in general actually. I will try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `.val()` callback function:

```
$('#one').click(function() {
    $('#numfield').val(function(_, val){
        return val + 'a';
    });
 });
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mj5wd9ak/)

Answer (score 0):

Just look to this line bellow

```
$('#textarea').val($('#textarea').val()+'a');
```

Full page example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {

     $('#textarea').val($('#textarea').val()+'a');
     });

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <textarea readonly="readonly" id="textarea"></textarea>
    <input type ="button" value="a" id="button"/>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
   var $ta = $('textarea');
  $ta.val($ta.val() + 'a');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea readonly="readonly" id="textarea"></textarea>
<input type ="button" value="a" id="button"/>
```